# set default value on array

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to pass in an array to a function and return that same array object back out?

```
function array_setdefault($arr, $key, $dflt) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
        return $arr[$key];
    }
    $arr[$key] = $dflt;
    return $arr[$key];
}

$errors = ["foo" => ["bar"]];
array_push(array_setdefault($errors, "foo", []), "bim");
array_push(array_setdefault($errors, "bla", []), "wub");

var_dump($errors);
```

leads to:

```
array(1) {
    ["foo"]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "bar"
    }
}
```

but I'd like to have:

```
array(2) {
    ["foo"]=>
    array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "bar"
        [1]=>
        string(3) "bim"
    }
    ["bla"]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "wub"
    }
}
```

I.e. $dflt should be set on the array for the $key in case it's not been set. If it has been set previously or after it's set in the current call to array_setdefault, return what's at $arr[$key] (that is, the $dflt array object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a reference argument so that changes in the function will modify the original variable, and also return a reference.

```
function &array_setdefault(&$arr, $key, $dflt) {
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
        $arr[$key] = $dflt;
    }
    return $arr[$key];
}
```

Putting `&` before the function name makes it return a reference. Putting `&` before a parameter makes that parameter a reference argument.

Comment: By-ref as argument **and** as return value... That's going to go wrong at some point.

Comment: Is there a comparable functionalit built into the language?

Comment: I can't think of anything simple.